# Python - randint() returns empty range, crashing error

Tags: python, random, crash

I've been able to duplicate this error multiple times in my poker program and tried various unsuccessful solutions. Here's the latest:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pangloss\Desktop\tgchanpoker\poker.py", line 1868, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': main()
  File "C:\Users\Pangloss\Desktop\tgchanpoker\poker.py", line 1866, in main
    mainGame = Game(opponent)
  File "C:\Users\Pangloss\Desktop\tgchanpoker\poker.py", line 1443, in __init__
    if randint(1,betCheck+(10-handValue[1]))<5 or gameStage == "bettingStay":
  File "C:\Python27\lib\random.py", line 241, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\random.py", line 217, in randrange
    raise ValueError, "empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width)
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (1,-7, -8)
```

And here's the relevant code:

```
                    handValue = checkHand(opponent.cards.cards)
                    if gameStage == "betting" or gameStage == "final" or gameStage == "finalresponding":
                        betCheck = 18-handValue[1]-round(betAmount/(setMax/5))+opponent.brashness
                    elif gameStage == "extendedFinal":
                        betCheck = 16-handValue[1]-round(betAmount/(setMax/5))+opponent.brashness-(pot/100)
                    else:
                        betCheck = 16-handValue[1]-round(betAmount/(setMax/5))+opponent.brashness
                    foldCheck = 16-handValue[1]-round(betAmount/(setMax/3))+opponent.brashness+(pot/100)
                    if randint(1,betCheck+(10-handValue[1]))<5 or gameStage == "bettingStay":
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code

```
randint(1,betCheck+(10-handValue[1]))
```

is giving you this

```
randrange(1,-7,-8)
```

This means that `betCheck+(10-handValue[1])` is giving you -8

That range will not give you any number at all, because betCheck+(10-handValue[1])) is a negative number and the range is invalid

You need to examine the code that sets betcheck and handvalue[1] to see why it is so negative

Comment: just `randint(1, -8)`, not -7. The -7 is the debug info and the call to `randint(1, -7, -8)` will raise an exception.

Comment: the -7 is from randrange, which is what randInt itself calls

Comment: No, I don't think it's from `randrange`. -7 here means the endpoint. See the traceback, when `randint` called, it turns to `return self.randrange(a, b+1)`. The third argument of `randrange` is the *step*. And see the traceback, it represents width. Since it's from positive to negative, it's also negative.

Answer (score 0):

Check your value of `betCheck+(10-handValue[1])`. From the traceback, it is -8.